# Number representation similar to base conversion

Tags: php, string, numbers, base-conversion

I'm trying to figure out how to make base conversion (base 36) use 0 as first character.

I want to represent positive integers using a scheme where `1` is represented as `0`, `10` is represented as `9`, `11` is represented as `a`, and so own, where leading zeroes are significant.

So `convert(36)` should give me `z` and then `convert(37)` should give me `00`.

I figured that this format is similar enough to base 36 that I should be able to use [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) to do it, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: How would you reverse it if you started reusing characters... I mean, if `0 = 1` and `00 = 36`, how do you know if `00` is `11` or `36`

Comment: so you want to convert n-1?

Comment: @crush its easy to reverse with base_convert :)@beat yeah basically, but does base_convert return 0?

Comment: @MadMarvin No, it's not easy to reverse. Explain the logic you'd use in the situation I gave. I'll be waiting.

Comment: I don't think that you are describing a valid numbering scheme. You want 1 mapped to 0, 10 mapped to 9, etc. What is 0 mapped to?

Comment: So you want character `0` to represent number `1`, character `9` to represent number `10` and character `a` to represent number `11`? If so what character will be representing number `0` ?

Comment: -1: You're not explaining thoroughly what you want.

Comment: -1: What you're asking is impossible, and doesn't even pass simple logic.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller - 0 as a value doesnt exist. Only 1 and above.

Comment: What you initially said wasn't possible. After we dragged it out of you, it became clear what you were really after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does the conversion the way you want. It could probably be done a lot more efficiently, but at least this gets it done:

```
function base_convert_0($number, $from_base, $to_base){
    $numeric = base_convert($number, $from_base, 10);

    $result = ''; 
    while($numeric > $to_base){
        $result = base_convert(($numeric - 1) % $to_base, 10, 36) . $result;

        $numeric = floor(($numeric - 1)/$to_base);
    }   
    $result = base_convert(($numeric - 1), 10, 36) . $result;

    return $result;
}
```

#### 5000 lines of output

80 lines shown here (`base_convert_0($i, 10, 36)`):

```
1: 0
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 4
6: 5
7: 6
8: 7
9: 8
10: 9
11: a
12: b
13: c
14: d
15: e
16: f
17: g
18: h
19: i
20: j
21: k
22: l
23: m
24: n
25: o
26: p
27: q
28: r
29: s
30: t
31: u
32: v
33: w
34: x
35: y
36: z
37: 00
38: 01
39: 02
40: 03
41: 04
42: 05
43: 06
44: 07
45: 08
46: 09
47: 0a
48: 0b
49: 0c
50: 0d
51: 0e
52: 0f
53: 0g
54: 0h
55: 0i
56: 0j
57: 0k
58: 0l
59: 0m
60: 0n
61: 0o
62: 0p
63: 0q
64: 0r
65: 0s
66: 0t
67: 0u
68: 0v
69: 0w
70: 0x
71: 0y
72: 0z
73: 10
74: 11
75: 12
76: 13
77: 14
78: 15
79: 16
80: 17
```

I'm not sure if you need to reverse this, but that's the easy part anyway:

```
function base_convert_un0($number, $from_base, $to_base){
    $as_string = strval($number);
    for($result = $j = 0, $i = strlen($as_string); $i--; $j++)
        $result += (base_convert($as_string{$i}, $from_base, 10) + 1)*pow($from_base, $j);
    return base_convert($result, 10, $to_base);
}
```

Comment: That looks pretty damn perfect. I'll take a look at it tomorrow. Thank you so much for not being just another basher. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Good luck converting these back to base 10.

Comment: I guess my real problem with this is that you don't have a base, yet want to use `base_convert`. Your base is infinity.

Comment: It fits the required transformations, but this doesn't convert to another base – it converts to a string representing the number.

Comment: @crush The base isn't infinity. There is no base. It is a string representation which has similarities to base 36. That's what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Beat Yes, it does exactly what the OP wanted. The OP didn't ask for base conversions to a made-up base. They asked for a representation of positive numbers that is similar to the base representation, but not in fact any valid base representation.

Comment: @MadMarvin You're welcome. Let me know if you find any mistakes in it, so I can fix it :)

Comment: @Paulpro he does talk about base36... But apart from that: I'd prefere your solution without the words "base_covert" in the function name; it is misleading.

Comment: @Beat I agree with you. I will rename it.

Comment: @Beat Although I am having trouble coming up with a good name. It uses base_convert internally and takes in arguments $from_base and $to_base.`$from_base` is actually the correct name when converting from a number, and `$to_base` is correct` when converting back, but the other two arguments are not named correctly either since the output for the forward conversion is not a number and neither is the input  for the reverse conversion.

Comment: @Paulpro It worked great. Perfect for my application. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand the point of your transformation, but don't you just try to convert n-1?

```
base_convert ($number_to_convert - 1, 10, 36);
```

**EDIT**: If 1<sub>base 10</sub> transforms to 0<sub>your special base</sub> – what character will you use for 0? I don't think your system can be used for valid notations of numbers.

**EDIT2**: I've probably understood the question in a too mathematical way. Please refer to @Paulpro's answer for a pragmatic solution to the problem (that isn't actually converting to another base but returning a string representing the input number).

Comment: It seems best not to even attempt to help people like this out. Seems they just want to downvote anyone who isn't a mind reader or who doesn't accomplish the impossible.

Comment: I haven't down voted anything. Stop being so negative, I asked on SO cause I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: @crush It wasn't Mad Marvin who downvoted this. I downvoted it, because the question is clear and this doesn't answer it.

Comment: @Paulpro what MadMarvin is requesting is impossible within the confines of the question.

Comment: @crush No it's not. He didn't say that `0` has to map to anything. He has given a sequence for 1 onwards and asked how to map the positive integers.

Comment: @Paulpro He wants `z` to map to `35` and `zz` to map to `62`. Interpreting `zz`, is that 35 twice or 62? You simply can't know. He'd have to introduce some type of separator, which is outside the scope of `base_convert` anyways.

Comment: What do you mean? `z` normally maps to `35` in base 36. In his scheme it maps to `36` and `zz` maps to `1332`.

Comment: @Paulpro Map them to whatever you want. You still can't interpret them in reverse order because you can't know if it's two `z` or a single `zz`

Comment: @crush That's like saying that you can't know if `22` is twenty-two or two `2`s. The natural numbers in our everyday decimal representation have that same "flaw" and it seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Paulpro There is a reason hexadecimal uses a-f instead of reusing 0-9. Think about it.

Comment: @crush I'll just post an answer, so you can understand how I interpret the question.

Comment: 22 makes sense in base-10. zz would make sense in base 36. It doesn't however, make sense in this infinite base schematic the OP has offered.

Comment: @crush Please see my answer which converts from the positive integers to the sequence the OP described. Converting back to the positive integers is the easy part.

Comment: @Paulpro If it's so easy, why didn't you do it. You can't convert them back to base 10 for the exact reason I've been harping about this entire time.

Comment: @crush I added a function to convert them back.

Comment: @crush Just lose the attitude - Paulpro solved the my question without fuzz.

Comment: @MadMarvin Lose the attitude? You asked a terribly worded question. You didn't address the concerns with that question until we dragged it out of you. Then you gave us attitude back. What you initially asked was impossible. After it became clear that you weren't trying to make a base conversion at all, the question became do able. Next time, stop and think about what exactly it is that you want. When you figure that out, word it clearly. You'll get a better reception that way. If you are unwilling to do that, then accept the criticism you receive. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @crush I understand that I could've expressed myself more clearly and I do accept the criticism, however, Paulpro understood the very first post, and that's what I mean - he interpreted it correctly. You didn't. No need to spam the entire question with "this can't be done" comments. Obviously it could be done, just not the way you thought about. (Yes, I know that it's not a "base conversion" per se, honestly I couldn't care less.)

Comment: @MadMarvin You were talking about a base conversion into `base36` and that couldn't be done and that makes it a bad question – it is misleading.